# Drag UIVIew relative to finger

Tags: ios, uiview, coordinates, drag, touchesmoved

I have a little problem.
I have some UIView and I'm able to drag them with methods touchesBegan and touchesMoved.

My problem is my UIView's coordinates (0,0) is coming under my finger. I would like to avoid that.

Do you know how to do that. I try some things but with no success :(

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the size of the view but you can probably set the `center` property to your touch's location.

**Animating the center to your tap location**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut)
                 animations:^{
                     theView.center = tapLocation;
                 }
                 completion:NULL]
```

Instead of just moving the location or translating it, you can animate the view to your current touch in all `touches*` methods.

Comment: It will cause an effect of "jump". I would like that the view follow exactly my finger where I taped it the first time.

Comment: Oh so you want to animate it to your position?

Comment: Could you not simply calculate the difference between the initial touch and the center, and subtract that from the touchesMoved value?

Comment: Yes that's your solution the good one. Thnaks a lot. I didn't thought about save the difference. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

when you press down your finger save the point

then measure the speed of the drag, and apply the speed to the position of your view (I translate my view with origin in my exemple)

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSUInteger touchCount = [touches count];
    NSUInteger tapCount = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
    NSLog(@"%d touches", touchCount);
    NSLog(@"%d taps", tapCount);

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    pNow = [touch locationInView:self];
    pLast = [touch locationInView:self];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSUInteger touchCount = [touches count];
    NSUInteger tapCount = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];
    NSLog(@"touchesMoved");
    NSLog(@"%d touches", touchCount);
    NSLog(@"%d taps", tapCount);

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    pNow = [touch locationInView:self];

    mouseSpeed.x = pNow.x - pLast.x;
    mouseSpeed.y = pNow.y - pLast.y;
    NSLog(@"mouseSpeed : %f, %f", mouseSpeed.x, mouseSpeed.y);

    origin.x += mouseSpeed.x;
    origin.y += mouseSpeed.y;
    NSLog(@"origin : %f, %f", origin.x, origin.y);

    //copy point for the next update
    pLast = pNow;
}
```